# azure devops docker file , use feed

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile

I searching the syntax to do dotnet restore with azure devops feed and not global nuget.

```
ARG nuget_repository=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
RUN dotnet restore "Xyz.csproj" -s ${nuget_repository}
```

i have the id of the feed

Answer (score 0):

You could check the Azure Nuget feed URL from Azure Artifacts -> Connect to feed -> Nuget
[image]

Sample:

```
ARG PAT=xx
RUN dotnet restore "Xyz.csproj" -s
https://:${PAT}@pkgs.dev.azure.com/AzureTest23/_packaging/234/nuget/v3/index.json
```